# Jquery selector giving "unexpected string" error

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select a table inside a form.  Here is my html:

```
<div id="switcher-panel">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="user/1/advancement" method="post">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>...<thead>
      <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

I can easily select the div "switcher-panel" with `$('#switcher-panel')`, but when I try to drill down to the table through the form with `$('#switcher-panel' 'form')` I get an `Unexpected String` error with a type of `unexpected_token_string`.  I thought I had a pretty decent grasp on Jquery, but I am at a lost here.  Is there a way to pass through the form or select the form that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#switcher-panel form")
```

or this:

```
$("#switcher-panel").find("form");
```

Otherwise, it is invalid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#switcher-panel').find('form')
```

What you are trying is not a legal selector. This will find the `form` element which is the child of the `div`.

You can also try `$('#switcher-panel form')` or `$('#switcher-panel').children('form')` which are pretty much the same things

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put `form` in single `quotes` again.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uPX99/1/)**

Change

```
$('#switcher-panel' 'form')
```

To

```
$('#switcher-panel form')
```